# Class 'MainAdapter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member

Tags: android-studio

I saw a prompt in my kotlin app build.gradle to upgrade these libraries:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

to version 27.1.0
After I did the upgrade and synced, one of my classes which is the adapter for a recyclerview is underlined red and the error is:
 "Class 'MainAdapter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member"

This class and the rest of the app worked perfectly before the change.
Should I roll back to 27.0.2 or is there a workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MainAdapter.itemNotaHolder {.....`

remove the "?" from `parent:ViewGroup`

`override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainAdapter.itemNotaHolder?, position: Int) {`

remove the "?" from `holder: MainAdapter.itemNotaHolder`

Comment: spent an hour trying to fix this

Comment: this couldn't be more accurate